# Groovy <g:form> validate using jquery validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, grails

below is example of form validation using jquery what I copied from internet,

however, when I used `<g:form>` instead of `<form>`  validate function not work.

Please suggest better way to validate form using groovy form

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>

  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link href="runnable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- Load jQuery and the validate plugin -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery Form Validation code -->
  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Register here</h1>

  <!--  The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit  -->
  <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div class="label">Password</div><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

  </form>

</body>
</html
```

Comment: Can you check that the form element generated by <g:from> in browser is same to the <form> element you used otherwise.

Comment: Well, when I used <g:form> and click on button, it executes submit action before I validate fields.

Comment: Might be you can go to ViewSource of your page on browser and compare the html generated when you use <g:form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` tag contains `novalidate` Attribute which Indicates that the form is not to be validated on submit, get rid of that first. Following is sample code from test project to use jquery validation with `<g:form>`. Sorry for long code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="esn-registration">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("emailId", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value);
     }, "Email is invalid: Enter a valid email");

    $.validator.addMethod("username", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z][\w.-]{3,20}$/i.test(value);
     }, "Characters, numbers, ( _ ), ( - ) and ( . ) only");

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required",
            emailId: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                emailId: true
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 20,
                username: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: { required: "Please enter your first name" },
            lastName: { required: "Please enter your last name" },
            emailId: {
                required: "Please enter an email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            username: {
                required: "Please enter an username",
                minlength: "Username must exceed 3 characters",
                maxlength: "Username cannot exceed 20 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Password must exceed 6 characters"
            }
        },

         submitHandler: function(form) {

            if(signupForm.valid()){
                form.submit();
                 $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }

             }

        });

    // validate login form on keyup and submit
    $("#loginForm").validate({
        rules: {
            username: "required",
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please enter an username or email",
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Password must exceed 6 characters"
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {

            if(loginForm.valid()){
                form.submit();
                 $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }

             }

        });

     // propose username by combining first and lastname
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        if(firstName && lastName && !this.value) {
            this.value = $.trim(firstName) + "." + $.trim(lastName);
        }
    }); 
});

</script>
<title>ESN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="front-card">
        <div class="front-welcome">
            <div class="front-welcome-text">
                <h3>Welcome</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="front-login">
            <g:form name="loginForm" controller="login" action="validate"
                method="POST" class="form well well-small container-fluid span3.5">
                <div id="login-form">
                    <div class="placeholding-login-username">
                        <input id="user-name" name="username"
                            value="${loginInstance?.username }"
                            placeholder="Username or email" class="input-xlarge" type="text"
                            maxlength="100" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="placeholding-login-password">
                        <input id="password" name="password"
                            value="${loginInstance?.password }"
                            placeholder="Password(min. length 6)" class="input-xlarge"
                            type="password" maxlength="30" required/>
                    </div>
                    <g:if test="${message}">
                        <div class="message text-error" role="status">
                            <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                                <li>
                                    ${message}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </g:if>
                    <div class="button pull-right">
                        <button name="submit" class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </g:form>
        </div>

        <div class="front-signup">
            <g:form name="signupForm" action="save" method="POST"
                class="form well well-small container-fluid span3.5">
                <div id="signup-form">
                    <fieldset class="form">
                        <legend>
                            <h5>
                                <strong class="muted">New to ESN?</strong> <strong
                                    class="text-info"> Sign up</strong>
                            </h5>
                        </legend>
                        <div class="placeholding-first-name">
                            <input id="firstName" name="firstName"
                                value="${userInstance?.firstName}" placeholder="First name"
                                class="input-xlarge" type="text" maxlength="150" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="placeholding-last-name">
                            <input id="lastName" name="lastName"
                                value="${userInstance?.lastName}" placeholder="Last name"
                                class="input-xlarge" type="text" maxlength="150" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="placeholding-email-id">
                            <input id="emailId" name="emailId"
                                value="${userInstance?.emailId}" placeholder="Email Id(Corporate)"
                                class="input-xlarge" type="email" maxlength="100" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="placeholding-signup-username">
                            <input id="username" name="username"
                                value="${userInstance?.username}" placeholder="Username"
                                class="input-xlarge" type="text" maxlength="20" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="placeholding-signup-password">
                            <input id="password" name="password"
                                value="${userInstance?.password}"
                                placeholder="Password(min. length 6)" class="input-xlarge"
                                type="password" maxlength="30" required/>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="button pull-right">
                        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign
                            up</button>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div>
                        <g:if test="${blankMessage}">
                            <div class="message text-error" role="status">
                                <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                                    <li>
                                        ${blankMessage}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:hasErrors bean="${userInstance}">
                            <div class="text-error">
                                <ul class="errors" role="alert">
                                    <g:eachError bean="${userInstance}" var="error">
                                        <li
                                            <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message
                                                error="${error}" /></li>
                                    </g:eachError>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </g:hasErrors>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </g:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it gave me new idea, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome bro. I am glad it not only helped you but gave you a new idea.